# Can you use contains() to remove the row above in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got a script that removes 'Reversals' from a list of transactions at work using `str.contains` that works as follows:

```
df = df[~df.claimOrReversal.str.contains("R", na=False)]
```

The dataframe column it's performing the operation on looks like this:

| ClaimOrReversal |
| --- |
| C |
| C |
| R |
| C |
| R |
| C |

And the finished result is:

| ClaimOrReversal |
| --- |
| C |
| C |
| C |
| C |

However, we need to consistently remove both the R's and the C one row before the R. The way the system works, there is always a claim before a reversal, so simply removing the reversal and row above the reversal will always work. However, I'm unsure how to do this with contains() and I think I may have to use numpy indexing instead?

Actual desired result would look like:

| ClaimOrReversal |
| --- |
| C |
| C |

Comment: It's probably better to identify rows to drop directly, but you can drop rows by index value

Comment: For example: do you know for certain that every `R` row is always associated with it's direct predecessor?

Comment: Yes, the direct predecessor of an R row is essentially a duplicate. There's more information in the dataframe than just the ClaimOrReversal column, it's just the only thing that changes between the two rows. The challenge I'm facing is removing these duplicates before the R's without removing any actual transactions. Transactions that need to be removed will always be a pair of a C and an R with otherwise identical information.

Comment: If you post `df.head(10).to_dict()` (and indicate what rules are for matching C, R rows), you may get a more robust solution

Comment: I'll have to make some fake data in the same format, I can't actually post the contents of the dataframe currently as it contains personal information/names/addresses etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a temporary column, `tmp` containing `df.ClaimOrReversal.shift(-1)`.

Then you can delete R both in `df.ClaimOrReversal` and `df.tmp`

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(["C", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C"], columns=["ClaimOrReversal"])

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
  ClaimOrReversal
0               C
1               C
2               R
3               C
4               R
5               C

In [4]: df["tmp"] = df.ClaimOrReversal.shift(-1)
   ...: df
Out[4]:
  ClaimOrReversal  tmp
0               C    C
1               C    R
2               R    C
3               C    R
4               R    C
5               C  NaN

In [5]: df.drop(df.query('tmp == "R" or ClaimOrReversal=="R"').index)[["ClaimOrReversal"]]
Out[5]:
  ClaimOrReversal
0               C
5               C
```

Comment: Seems like a pretty clever solution. I'll have to make sure it's consistently working with the dataset I have but this might be the answer.